# Prevent Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement from running on every submit

Tags: c#, asp.net

Three different actions. Two of which I want this called. One of which I don't.
I have a drop down list and a button (both as template fields within a GridView) that execute various methods. When they're doing their business this line runs while the server is executing. I have this in the page load method of code behind.

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(this.GetType(), "submit", "check();");
```

It works perfectly for these actions. Server finishes and the "check()" JS method ends. However,

I have another method that exports a gridview to an excel document. That same call in the page load runs and never goes away till I physically go up to the URL and reload the page.

In order for the export method to work correctly, the last line of the method is

```
Response.End(); Call
```

I have tried using two different calls to reload the page. Neither work

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
```

However, when I flip the

```
Response.End();
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
```

To

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
Response.End();
```

It of course will work and will refresh the page,  but it does not finish the export correctly.

Is there anyone that can help with this problem? Thanks

Comment: That is because you can only send one thing at a time to the client. Either an Excel document OR an html page in which `check();` is added in Page_Load.

Comment: @VDWWD is there a way to stop the check() script from running in page load when that Excel doc is being sent? Or when that specific ASP button is pressed?